How do I remove and replace line breaks from my clipboard while using snippets in Visual Studio Code?
I am planning to replace every line break in my clipboard with a space, followed a vertical bar and then another space.
For instance, if my clipboard has the following text:
My
Clipboard
Content

the output should be something like this: My | Clipboard | Content
Based on the documentation provided by VS Code themselves, I have put the regular expression into the CLIPBOARD variable like this: ${CLIPBOARD/[\n]/ | /g}. However, when I try to use the snippet, the vertical bars get added, but the line breaks are not removed.
With the same input earlier, my output is now:
My
 | Clipboard
 | Content


This snippet would do what you are asking:
"Paste Multi-line To Single Line":{
        "prefix": "pasteMultiLineToSingleLine"
        ,"body": ["${CLIPBOARD/(\r\n|\n|\r)/ | /g}"]
        ,"description": "Paste from clipboard replacing every new line with a ' | '"
    }

The main difference is in identifying the different possible line ending characters.
Further explanation of the "body": in case someone else likes to understand the individual parts:

Parts are separated by /
${CLIPBOARD} = Gets the contents of your clipboard.
See variable reference page [1].
(\r\n|\n|\r) = This part gets uses regex to get all possible line endings.

| = read as 'OR'
\r\n = Windows line endings
\n = Unix line endings
\r = Very old Mac systems line ending. Might be able to do without this one. I'm just in the habit of having all cases covered.


| = This is the replacement text.
There is a whitespace on either side of the bar |
g = regex option to find and replace all 'global' instances and not just the first occurrence.

Reference:
[1] VSCode Snippet Variables: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_variables
[2] Stackoverflow ref1: Match linebreaks - \n or \r\n?
[3] Stackoverflow ref2: Difference between \n and \r?
